# Vue.js - call API and render response from child single-file component

Tags: javascript, ajax, vuejs2

Vue.js version 2, with single-file components and vue-router (and webpack but that shouldn't be important here).

I've researched this as well as I believe I can and cannot seem to unravel a good pattern for **populating and rendering an object** when a component is rendered, hoping the solution is obvious to someone and easily explained.

**Main.js** (called from webpack.base.config):

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

**App.vue:**

```
<template>
    <router-view></router-view>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
      name: 'app'
    }
</script>
```

**Child.vue** (it's important to note that what I'm doing here is 1) making an api call (via javascript promise) 2) iterating the response and populating the temp `Object` `let x = {}` properties with keys and values of each important bit then 3) triggering the `computed.cObj.set()` in effort to render the list):

```
<template>
  <div class="child">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="i in cObj">{{ i }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
      name: 'child',
      data () {
        return {
          obj: {}
        }
      },
      computed: {
        cObj: {
          get: function () {
            return this.obj
          },
          set: function (nv) {
            this.obj= nv
          }
        },
        // cObj: function () {
          // return this.getAll()
        // }
      },
      created () {
        let conditional = true
        if (!conditional) // ...do something else
        else this.getAllX()
      },
      methods: {
        getAll: function () {
          let x = {} // temporary object

          // in this promise I'm returning data from the server
          server.getData()
            .then(function (r) {

              // iterate response
              r.records[0].operations().then(r => {
                for (let a in r) {
                  if (typeof r[a].records === 'object') {
                    for (let b in r[a].records) {
                      Object.keys(r[a].records[b]).forEach(function (key) {
                        if (r[a].records[b][key] !== undefined) {
                          // add key/value to x
                          x[key] = r[a].records[b][key]
                        }
                      })
                    }
                  }
                }
              })
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
              console.log(err)
            })
          this.cObj = x // THIS IS WHAT IS KILLING ME HERE, I must be misunderstanding the documentation here because the computed `set` method isn't triggered or I'm misunderstanding vue lifecycle, I thought calling the computed.cObj.set() should trigger the rendering of the list but it does not. 
          // return x | tried this as well (see commented out computed.cObj)
        }
      }
    }
</script>
```

Looking at the populated object in console I get the following but the list isn't rendered:

```
// {}
// detailOne: "asdf"
// detailTwo: "asdf asdf"
// __proto__: Object { … }
```

Here is a similar question [Vue.js : How to make dynamic menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42690731/1848540)

Comment: Why do you need a computed property for this? You can initiate your `cObj` as data and then simply set it like you do by `this.cObj = x;`

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot. Correct me if I'm wrong, if I understand that correctly you're saying I should set `this.data = x`. EDIT: I believe you mean move the computed `cObj` to data, trying that.

Comment: Nope. I'll give you a more complete sample. Just a minute :)

Comment: Yep, moving `cObj` to data :)

Comment: Ok, thanks... testing. EDIT: Bummer! Didn't work either. As before the `cObj` is populated (per console output) but the component doesn't render the data after the object is populated :/.

Comment: Hm ... I updated the code below. It should work like this (it do here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your **Child.vue**:

The Array Way:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(item, index) in cObj" :key="index">{{ item.name }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      cObj: {}
    }
  },
  created () {
      let conditional = true
      if (!conditional) {

      }
      else {
        this.getAll()
      }
    },
    methods: {
      getAll: function () {
        let x = [
          { id: 1, name: 'one' },
          { id: 2, name: 'two' },
          { id: 3, name: 'thre' },
        ]
        this.cObj = x;
      }
    }
}
</script>
```

The Object Way:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(value, key) in cObj" :key="key">{{ key }} : {{ value.name }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      cObj: {}
    }
  },
  created () {
      let conditional = true
      if (!conditional) {

      }
      else {
        this.getAll()
      }
    },
    methods: {
      getAll: function () {
        let x = {
          first: { id: 1, name: 'one' },
          second: { id: 2, name: 'two' },
          third: { id: 3, name: 'three' },
        };
        this.cObj = x;
      }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Per your edit, the object is different than what I'm getting (please see commented out object near the end of the original post). Is it likely the object is the issue here? Sidenote, I believed the this issue was my lack of understanding regarding the lifecycle because I've seen the list populate, but when it populated it was a hack of sorts becuase it only rendered when I saved a change to the code and the hot-reload was triggered (but of course I couldn't get the list to render naturally). I'll try to render it as an array (of objects) as you have.

Comment: Excuse me. It should works for arrays and objects as well. 
Arrays: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mapping-an-Array-to-Elements-with-v-for, Objects: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-an-Object

Comment: I updated the code to demonstrate that both ways works. Hopefully for you as well.

Comment: thank you again, and ...agreed... but what I'm finding is that the object I'm building may be problematic and in your example a missing "key part" of my issue is looping through the response and building a temp object and setting the temp object to the vue data item. I'm pretty sure that what you've listed as an answer will help all who face this same issue but I need it to work locally before I can close this out so I'm trying to find where I'm failing locally and will be select answer asap.

Comment: Thank you, after meddling, setting x to an array and using `x.push(...` made the final difference for me. Key reason I selected this as an answer was that the `computed:` property wasn't necessary.